# Active Record generating a wrong query

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, heroku, sinatra

I'm trying to do an extremely simple active record query :

```
@row = Blazer.where(username: 'test').first
```

PostgreSQL generation :

```
Blazer.where(username: 'test').to_sql
```

outputs :

```
SELECT "blazer".* FROM "blazer" WHERE "username"."value" = 'test'
```

which causes an error :

```
ERROR -- : PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "username"
```

I expected the following PostgreSQL result :

```
SELECT "blazer".* FROM "blazer" WHERE "username" = 'test'
```

How can I fix this?

I'm using active record with Sinatra and the app runs on Heroku.

My Blazer class is the following :

```
class Blazer < ActiveRecord::Base
    # phone:string username:string location:string
end
```

Comment: Hmm, this is rather bizarre. What does `Blazer.where(phone: 'x').to_sql` say?

Comment: Gemfile`Using arel (4.0.1)Using activerecord (4.0.2)Using pg (0.17.1)
` then test it with:

`User.where(first_name: 'Tom').to_sql` outputs:
`SELECT "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."first_name" = 'Tom'`

Check on `default_scope`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not the correct answer, but I was getting the same error.

I was looking for a Venue with a certain name

```
venue_name = params.require(:season).permit([:venue_name])
venue = Venue.find_by_name(venue_name)
```

I also tried with

```
venue = Venue.where(name: venue_name).first
```

Both failed saying because it was trying this query

```
SELECT  "venues".* FROM "venues"  WHERE "name"."venue_name" = 'venue name' LIMIT 1)
```

When I was trying this in the console everything looked OK. But when I checked what I was looking for was quite obvious

```
params.require(:season).permit([:venue_name])
```

Returns a Hash with only venue_name as key, so instead of looking for a key i was looking for a Hash.

I switched to `params.require(:season).permit([:venue_name])[:venue_name]` and the issue was fixed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll check it this evening.